# My 2016 Hyundai accent

Tags: engine, oil, hyundai, overheating, accent

I have a 2016 Hyundai accent and I do the oil change about last week if the and took out the oil and put it in different oil but for some reason as I hit the acceleration on the car it starts to sound like a loud noise like a clog somewhere where from the front

Comment: Did you replace the oil filler cap before you closed the hood?

Comment: You used the "overheating" tag, and yet, you didn't mention anything about it overheating? Did you forget to include something in your question?